# Cross-Validation?

Tags: webforms

My team is working on a registration form using the webform module.
One issue we are having is cross-validation.

We have a field for a parent or educator to enter in their username, after this they proceed to register students.

Setting up the individual fields is good. A user cannot enter the same parent username that is already in use or a student username that is already in use.

Where we are having difficulty is that a parent could enter a username of a student. In our case, it doesn't matter if it is a parent or student username, if the username is already in use an account will not be created.

How can we have the validation check both fields? (parent_username and student_username) to display an error if the username has previously been used in either field? Currently the entity validation only checks the same field.

TIA